# solo.clickInlist(int) not working for custom listview in Robotium

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I'm new to Robotium, I have two questions.
1) I'm trying to make click on custom listview item but its not working. I tried with clickInList(int) and clickInlist(int, int).

2) Handling random AlertDialog:
       How to handle display alert dialog dynamically in Robotium? For example I'm using alert dialog when I get any message during call webservice, like connection failure, no internet, server error, timeout, etc..,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the code for `solo.clickInList(int, int)`.

Comment: solo.clickInInList(0,1);

Comment: yes but what is `solo` and in what method is it called

Comment: Solo is the object of Robotium.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two important things to note about the `clickInList(int)` method that aren't readily apparent:  First, the list items are 1-indexed, so to click the first item of the list, use `clickInList(1)` not `clickInList(0)`.  Second, the clicking is relative to the visible items on the screen, so `clickInList(1)` will click the first visible item on the list, not the first item overall.

As for the dynamic handling of a Dialog, arbitrary pop-ups aren't really what Robotium was meant to handle. It's supposed to test user interaction with the app under known, controlled, repeatable conditions.  If something unexpected happens in the middle of the test, such as losing connection, it should be considered a failure; There's a good chance your test wouldn't be able to run to completion anyway.  As a hacky work-around, you can check for the existence of the Dialog before each of your events, something like:

```
if(solo.searchText("Dialog text") {
    //handle closing dialog
}
```

However, I'd advise against this, it'll slow down your test considerably, and again, even if you close the dialog, the fact that the error happened in the first place is probably going to cause a later part of your test to fail.

Comment: And to mention a trap that I just stepped into: If you call `clickInList(0)` Robotium just replaces `0` with `1` and continues processing the statement.